# RiotJS 3: calling in-tag functions

Tags: function, tags, riot.js

Let's suppose we have a Riot SPA like this:

index.html:

```
<my-tag></my-tag>
<script type="riot/tag" src="my-tag.riot"></script>
<script>
//OK we need a compile() wrapper to access all tag instances
var tags;
riot.compile(function() {
    tags = riot.mount('*');
    });
</script>
```

my-tag.riot:

```
<my-tag>
<p>My tag</p>
<script>
myFunction(){
console.log('doing stuff...')
}
</script>
</my-tag>
```

I would like to call myFunction() from index.html. In theory it could be something like this:

```
riot.compile(function() {
    tags = riot.mount('*');
    });
tags[0].myFunction();
```

In fact the tags array is unavailable outside the compile() wrapper
. Of course it's possible to call myFunction() from inside compile():

```
riot.compile(function() {
    tags = riot.mount('*');
    tags[0].myFunction();
    });
```

But I'm not sure it's a good approach. So what's the best practice to access the in-tag functions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same issue on plunker:
http://plnkr.co/2G3ReNBCpgCSgDZc1f9O

Answer (score 0):

Define tags variable globally and assign value inside compile callback.